# Wordpress on Azure App Service read Application settings

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a WordPress site running on Azure as an App Service.
I plan on using deployment slots to set up a test environment. 
I have some environment-specific settings. If I was running .NET I would read the app settings.

Is it possible for PHP to read app settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getenv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) to read a setting

```
getenv('settingname');
```